# dealloc called on same thread as running method causes crash by race condition, is that expected?

Tags: objective-c, ios, multithreading, thread-safety

I have an object called `MadsAdViewController` that requests ads asynchronously, and is called back on the method `didReceiveResponse`. In an app with a lot of memory usage the dealloc method is called really fast, and sometimes even when the `didReceiveResponse` method is still running. This causes crashes, as the result of what I would call a race condition. As the output shows, both `didReceiveResponse` and `dealloc` are called on the main thread.

Why isn't the `dealloc` waiting for the method to finish? And why does the `@synchronized` block not work? And how can I fix this?

```
-(void)didReceiveResponse:(MadsAdResponse*) inAdResponse {
    NSLog(@"didReceiveResponse: main thread? = %i, address = %p", [NSThread isMainThread], self);
    @synchronized (self) {
        //... (lots of stuff that takes a while)
        [self logEvent:logAction eventName:EVENT_INIT action:ACTION_VIEW extra:nil];  
    }
    NSLog(@"done with didReceiveResponse response")
}

- (void)dealloc {
    @synchronized (self) {
        NSLog(@"in sync block in dealloc of object %p", self);
        //lots of releases
    }
    [super dealloc]
}
```

and this is the output:

```
didReceiveResponse: main thread? = 1, address = 0x139d50b0
in sync block in dealloc of object 0x139d50b0
```

and then the app crashes:

```
*** -[[MadsAdViewController logEvent:eventName:action:extra:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x139d50b0
```

Comment: looks like something is calling logEvent:eventName:action:extra: after the dealloc.. if this class is being used as a delegate, are you setting the "owner's" delegate property to nil before the dealloc is called?

Comment: It's not a threading issue. You'll need to post more code from `didReceiveResponse`, but something that you're doing in there is releasing the current object.

Comment: If you put a breakpoint into dealloc, you can see where it's released by looking at the backtrace.

Comment: It is absolutely wrong to put @synchronized in dealloc, cause this method MUST be called only once. The real issue is that you probably over-releasing self object (maybe you've added it to some autorelease pool). Place a breakpoint in your dealloc as joerick suggested.

Comment: all right, adding a breakpoint in -dealloc

Comment: also logging retainCount on release and retain, goes up to 4... Something is wrong here

Comment: yes, my initial debugging shows the crashes are related to over-releasing. Too early to tell if I fixed all mistakes. TBC

Answer (score 0):

OK, turned to be a nice interaction between blocks and this piece of code listed above.

For context, our library was used by an external party in a way that we would not ahem recommend.

This is what happened around it:

```
XXXMadsAdViewController *adViewController = [[[XXXMadsAdViewController alloc]init]autorelease];
self.adViewController = adViewController;
[self.adViewController loadAdWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
     //stuff
}];
```

XXXMadsAdViewController both extended MadsAdViewController *as that it was* the delegate to receive the method call `didReceivePartialAd`.  `[self.delegate didReceivePartialAd]` is called in the method `didReceiveResponse` that I didn't include in the original question and that was called *before* `[self logEvent];`

Now, sometimes `self.adViewController` was already released, but this block was still waiting for the callback. On callback on `didReceivePartialAd`, the block was processed, `self.adViewController` released again and the app crashed.

I fixed the problem by making `didReceivePartialAd` the last statement of the method `didReceiveResponse`.

Thanks guys, without your pointers I would still think it was a race condition!